# floating issue with two containers

Tags: html, css

I have this markup:

```
div#wrapper
  ul#container1
    li#box1
    li#box2
    li#box3
  ul#container2
    li#box4
    li#box5
    li#box6
```

The screen's width is enough to display 5 boxes on one row, but the whole container 2 is below container 1 when I float left the uls

How can I have the first line on the screen display boxes 1 to 5 and the second line box 6 (as if all lis were inside a single container and floated left) while keeping the lis inside two different containers ?

Thanks

Comment: can you show your code for detail

Comment: Do u specify padding for ul#container1 ?

Comment: @kapillohakare: no, no padding

Comment: Can you edit the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `ul` elements `display: inline` and the `li` elements `display: inline-block`

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/hW7Aj/1/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li> 
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li> 
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    display: inline;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Works ok, but what about wider screens? Then the 6th li will also float to the top "row."

Comment: @RunningTurtle You're welcome! :) @-KyleSevenoaks I think that is what the OP was asking for, not?

Answer (score 1):

For html:

```
 <div>
    <ul class="li1">
        <li>c</li>
        <li>c</li>    
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="li1">
        <li>c</li>
        <li>c</li>    
        <li id="last">c</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .li1 {
        display: inline;
    }

    #last {
        clear: both;
    }
    li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you have display inline _and_ float left? one or the other should do.

Comment: Your CSS selector: `li {display: inline; float: left;}` doesn't need both float: left; and display: inline; Choose one :)

Comment: Yes, we can use display:inline once but float:left is required.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with such markup you can't do this because if you floating `ul` and `li` to the left you will have each `ul` as a container with the floated elements and you don't have enought space to plase 2 floated `ul` elements. That's why you have wrapped second `ul` to new line.

You can solve this problem by placing all floated elements under one container.

Answer (score 0):

You need two CSS rules:

```
ul.second li:nth-child(3)
{
    clear: both;
}

li {         
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>     
    <li>1</li>     
    <li>2</li>     
    <li>3</li>  
</ul>
<ul class="second">
    <li>4</li>     
    <li>5</li>     
    <li>6</li>  
</ul>
```

This is one way to do it, using the awesome nth-child pseudo selector.

---

If you have to support IE then you can change add a class to the last li

```
<ul>     
    <li>1</li>     
    <li>2</li>     
    <li>3</li>  
</ul>
<ul<
    <li>4</li>     
    <li>5</li>     
    <li class="myLi">6</li>  
</ul>
```

and change the CSS accordingly:

```
li.myLi    {
    clear: both;
}

li {         
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zN4W5/